# Setting Django DateRangeField parameters

Tags: django, postgresql

I need to track people in their current positions. So in my model I can do:

```
tenure = models.DateRangeField(‘date of hire’, ‘date of termination’)
```

but what about someone who is currently still employed? Can I do:

```
tenure = models.DateRangeField(‘2006-10-10’, datetime.date.today())
```

or

```
tenure = models.DateRangeField(‘2006-10-10’, [)) ?
```

Then when this person terminates, I can change the value on the instance to a date certain, but will that cause a problem because the model field expects a function?

Eventually I am going to have to query against this date range, which is why I was looking at the new DateRangeField, but maybe I'd be better off with two plain date fields, one for start and one for termination?

Comment: Can you set date of termination to NULL?  Note that when querying a possibly NULL field, nothing equals NULL, not even NULL. If I don't know your birthdate, I'd put NULL in the 'birthdate' field. I'd also put NULL for Napoleon's birthday, because I don't know it either. But this does not mean you and Napoleon have the same birthday, even though they're both NULL. So the query syntax isn't 'x = NULL', but 'x IS NULL'.

Comment: If NULLs don't work, can you set the date of termination to the day before date of hire?

Answer (score 1):

`DateRangeField` takes the standard model field keyword arguments. The first two arguments would be interpreted as `Field.verbose_name` and `Field.name` based on the signature of `Field.__init__()`. It seems that you think it takes some arguments with some other meaning.